# how to make a loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, chess

I am trying to build an app similar to visions on chess.com, where you pick a side (e.g. white) and then a timer starts with 30 seconds and random coordinates show on the screen and you have to tap the corresponding tile on the chess board. If you pressed right, a counter increases by one and a new random coordinate is shown. If you press wrong the counter does not increase.

Im at a stage in my app where I have successfully implemented the board and general layout of the app

Chess Board implementation:

```
class BoardWhite extends StatelessWidget {
  const BoardWhite({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Chess Coordinates'),
      ),
      body: const ChessBoard(),
    );
  }
}

class ChessBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChessBoard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // Row with column labels
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: List.generate(8, (index) {
              return Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  String.fromCharCode('A'.codeUnitAt(0) + index),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
              height: 10), // Add a small space between row labels and board

          // Chessboard grid
          SizedBox(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 300.0,
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 8,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // Calculate the row and column for each tile
                final row = index ~/ 8;
                final col = index % 8;

                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // Handle tile click
                    print(
                        'Clicked on tile: ${String.fromCharCode('A'.codeUnitAt(0) + col)}${8 - row}');
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now I actually want to start a timer and display it above the chess board. I think I can do this by displaying the timer and the board in a column right?

Another problem I am facing is that I want to make kind of a while loop that is running while the countdown is not at zero. But I don't find any examples of something like that in the doc or by googling.

In my loop I would like to generate a random coordinate, show it in the middle of the board and if the user presses a tile I want to check if the coordinates match. Then I can change the counter corresponding to the outcome.
Can anyone help my by explaining how one could do that in flutter? My background is very limited as I wrote code mainly in C++.

It would be great if the answer contains code snippets or links where I can find more.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` class. It has two constuctors:

1. Simple `Timer(duration, callback)` - for oneshot callback invocation after delay.
2. Periodic `Timer.periodic(duration, callback)` - for periodic callback invocations.

To cancel it simply call `myTimer.cancel()`.